# Convert string array to int array (generics?)

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a string that I want to split with a certain delimiter

```
private int [] mMaxValues;

    public void setMaximum(String maximum) {
       mMaxValues = splitByDelimiter(maximum, ":");
    }
```

But the splitByDelimiter method return a string array into an int array

```
public String[] splitByDelimiter(String list,String delimiter) {
    String[] items = list.split("\\" + delimiter);

    for (String s : items) {
        s.trim();
    }

    return items;
}
```

What is the best way to fix this problem? I'm guessing that iterating the string array and casting them to integers isn't the best solution.

I could also create a new splitByDelimiter that returns an int array but I'm guessing there is a better solution than that..

Is this a situation where you could use generics (I don't have a lot of experience with generics)?

Thx :)

Comment: You can't cast a String to an `int`, you need to parse it and there is no way to do this automagically.

Comment: I guess your returned `String[]` only contains Strings that can be parsed to an Integer? In other words it contains numbers as Strings?!

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't doing anything. Strings are immutable, so you're trimming the copy of the strings in array.

Comment: No, it can also contain Strings that can't be converted to Integers. I use to split any string with a given delimiter a return an array.

Comment: So what should be done with the Strings in the returned `String[]` that cannot be parsed to an Integer? Do you simply want to ignore them? It's always useful to provide some sample input and the expected output. Input: `"bla:123:456:blub:789"`, Output: `{123,456,789}` or something like that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert string array to int array explicitly. Use:

```
public void setMaximum(String maximum) {
   Strin[] array = splitByDelimiter(maximum, ":");
   int i = 0;
   mMaxValues = new int[array.length];
   for (String value : array) {
       mMaxValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(value);
       i++;
   }
}
```

Also you need to handle few cases which may cause `NullPointerException` :

1. `maximum` is null
2. `array` is null
3. `NumberFormatException` may be raised while parsing `Integer.parseInt(value)`, handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the string array and store them in an int array.

```
String input = ...;
String[] parts = input.split(':');
int[] result = new int[parts.length];
for (int n = 0; n < parts.length; ++n)
{
  result[n] = Integer.parseInt(parts[n]);
}
return result
```

Comment: It appears he want to `trim()` each of the parts before parsing them.

Comment: That's a trivial change: parts[n].trim()

Comment: @iccthedral No it won't. Try `Integer.parseInt("  8  ")`. Gives a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @iccthedral No, it does not. It throws `NumberFormatException` in such cases.